# What is a bulk state and bulk bands?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, topological-phase

I am a bachelor student and I started studying topology and I came across two terms I have never seen before: Bulk band structure and bulk states.

Can someone explain these two terms or provide me a reference where I can check? Everything I found on the internet is for people who already know what are they.

thanks

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199717/meaning-of-the-term-bulk

Answer (score 1):

The bulk states are the quantum states of electron inside the volume (bulk) of a crystal, obtained from Schrödinger equation. These states are usually labeled by the two indices, n and k representing respectively the band index and wave number. The plot of the energy of these states versus k for various values of n is called bulk band structure. In contrast to bulk states are edge states, which are localized on the surface (boundaries) of crystal and not in the bulk.